# Plotting one x- vs multiple y- using custom color map

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot data that comes in the form of one x-axis vs multiple y-axis on the same plot. I would like the color of each line to spread itself out through my desired color map (spectrum coloring).

An example of the data I want plot can be found here: http://pastebin.com/R8nC0zq4

If I copy this data set into MATLAB, I can set up my plot to show an example of how I want it to ultimately look in pgfplots. Consider the pastebin code copied into `MATLAB`, residing in a variable named `data`:

```
cmp = jet(10);
hLine = plot(data(:,1),data(:,2:end)); %plot x vs all the y columns (10)
for line = 1:10
set(hLine(line),'Color',cmp(line,:));
end
set(hLine,'LineWidth',1.5);
```

The plot (which is just to illustrate what I want) looks as follows:

[image: example plot]

Without using `matlab2tikz`, how can I use the data provided in the pastebin link to directly recreate this same plot in pgfplots? Ideally the method should be able to automatically take any number of y-data and set the color of each line appropriately.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `\foreach` loop to plot all the columns, and change the colours by setting `mesh, point meta=<looping variable>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
x   y1  y2  y3  y4  y5  y6  y7  y8  y9  y10
0.001   0.9990005   0.947831109 0.899282645 0.853220861 0.809518389 0.768054383 0.728714188 0.691389021 0.65597567  0.622376212
0.053578947 0.998900605 0.94276631  0.889786543 0.839784031 0.792591464 0.748050933 0.706013406 0.666338223 0.62889263  0.593551332
0.106157895 0.99880072  0.937728576 0.880390717 0.826558809 0.776018478 0.72856846  0.684019795 0.64219508  0.602927757 0.566061454
0.158736842 0.998700845 0.93271776  0.871094107 0.813541862 0.759792031 0.709593394 0.662711326 0.618926706 0.578034888 0.539844748
0.211315789 0.99860098  0.927733721 0.861895666 0.800729911 0.743904877 0.69111252  0.642066654 0.596501404 0.554169761 0.51484225
0.263894737 0.998501124 0.922776314 0.852794357 0.788119727 0.728349922 0.673112969 0.622065102 0.574888628 0.531289946 0.490997723
0.316473684 0.998401279 0.917845397 0.843789155 0.775708133 0.713120219 0.655582203 0.602686635 0.554058939 0.509354762 0.468257537
0.369052632 0.998301444 0.912940828 0.834879045 0.763492001 0.698208966 0.638508014 0.583911842 0.533983962 0.488325209 0.446570545
0.421631579 0.998201619 0.908062468 0.826063022 0.751468253 0.683609507 0.62187851  0.565721919 0.514636354 0.468163895 0.42588797
0.474210526 0.998101804 0.903210176 0.817340093 0.739633859 0.66931532  0.605682111 0.548098645 0.495989759 0.448834974 0.406163293
0.526789474 0.998001999 0.898383812 0.808709275 0.727985838 0.655320022 0.589907536 0.531024368 0.478018778 0.43030408  0.38735215
0.579368421 0.997902203 0.893583238 0.800169596 0.716521254 0.641617365 0.574543798 0.514481986 0.460698932 0.412538264 0.36941223
0.631947368 0.997802418 0.888808316 0.791720092 0.705237218 0.628201228 0.559580199 0.49845493  0.444006628 0.39550594  0.352303183
0.684526316 0.997702643 0.884058909 0.783359812 0.694130888 0.615065621 0.545006316 0.482927146 0.427919129 0.379176823 0.33598653
0.737105263 0.997602878 0.879334882 0.775087814 0.683199464 0.602204678 0.530812001 0.467883081 0.412414521 0.363521881 0.320425569
0.789684211 0.997503122 0.874636097 0.766903165 0.672440192 0.589612656 0.516987366 0.453307666 0.397471685 0.348513279 0.305585303
0.842263158 0.997403377 0.86996242  0.758804943 0.661850361 0.577283931 0.503522784 0.439186301 0.383070267 0.334124332 0.291432352
0.894842105 0.997303642 0.865313718 0.750792236 0.651427302 0.565212998 0.490408879 0.425504844 0.369190649 0.320329456 0.277934885
0.947421053 0.997203916 0.860689856 0.742864139 0.64116839  0.553394467 0.477636516 0.412249588 0.355813925 0.307104125 0.265062542
1   0.997104201 0.856090703 0.735019761 0.631071038 0.541823059 0.4651968   0.399407259 0.342921874 0.294424823 0.252786372
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colormap/jet]
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
\addplot [very thick, no markers, mesh, point meta=\i] table [y index=\i] {data.txt};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did `foreach` suddenly started to expand things? I saw it on other questions too and I don't know why it is working. It shouldn't work in this case if we consider old answers no?